# How to write dictionary data in memory value directly to s3 bucket as in csv file without writing in file then uploading it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, csv, amazon-s3

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

BUCKET_NAME = ''
ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ''
Fraudfilekey = 'fraud_CT_ID_IM_NO/ CT_PROFILE_One_to_Many_Mapping /yyyy=2021/mm=02/dd=05/2021_02_05_CT_TEST.csv'

d = {"A" : ["John","Deep","Julia","Kate","Sandy"],
                     "MonthSales" : [25,30,35,40,45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-south-1', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
def write_to_s3_oneim_to_onect(df):
    s3.put_object(Body=df, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=Fraudfilekey)

write_to_s3_oneim_to_onect(df)
```

How can I write dictionary value directly to s3 bucket , I get Body below error
raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: A  MonthSales

Note: I want Headers col as IM No, CT ID in csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways. One would be to use `BytesIO` as a memory buffer for the file:

```
import io

def write_to_s3_oneim_to_onect(df):
    bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
    df.to_csv(bytes_io)
    s3.put_object(Body=bytes_io.getvalue(), 
                  Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, 
                  Key=Fraudfilekey)
```

Other would be to use [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which pandas supports. This would require you to install s3fs and setup AWS [credetnails](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials) for it to use. But once setup, writing to S3 would be:

```
def write_to_s3_oneim_to_onect(df):
    df.to_csv(f"s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{Fraudfilekey}")
```